# How can I unpack a Pydantic BaseModel into kwargs?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, pydantic

I am trying to make a function that takes a `pydantic BaseModel` as an input to run another function. I need to unpack the BaseModel into kwargs. I tried doing this:

```
def run_routing_from_job(job):
    return run_routing(
        job.inputs.input_file,
        **job.inputs.config.dict()
    )
```

where `job` is of the format

```
class Job(BaseModel):
    client_info: ClientInfo  # Another BaseModel
    inputs: RoutingJobInputs  # Another BaseModel
    uid: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    status: str = "job_queued"
    result: int = None
```

However, doing `.dict()` parses all of the items recursively into a dictionary format. I want to keep the `client_info` and `inputs` as a BaseModel class, not convert it into a dictionary.

I could make a way to do it, but I can't find a clean way to do it.

Comment: Why not just use a `job: Job` argument instead of `**kwargs`?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I was using someone elses code, I'm going to go back and modify it to accept `job` instead, but for now I just wanted to unpack the basemodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out, just replace `.dict()` with `__dict__`

```
def run_routing_from_job(job):
    return run_routing(
        job.inputs.input_file,
        **job.inputs.config.__dict__
    )
```